# How present currency value in French format in R

Tags: r, format, currency, french

I have part of code that should show currency value in a French format

This code

```
library(formattable)

currency(x = 123456, symbol = "€", digits = 0)
```

gives me "€123,456".

I need code that gives me **"123 456€"** in a French format for one single value.

Thanks!

Comment: Which package this method is from?

Comment: currency {formattable}

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do it with `currency` function. It seems to not take in consideration putting the symbol after.

You can maybe use `prettyNum` function from `base R` in combination with `paste` to add the symbol at the end:

```r
paste(prettyNum(x, big.mark = " ",big.interval = 3), "€")

[1] "123 456 €"
```

Alternatively, in `DT`, you can use `formatCurrency` function:

```r
library(DT)

x = 123456
datatable(as.matrix(x)) %>% formatCurrency(1, '\U20AC', digits = 0, before = FALSE, mark = "")
```

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: I had before the same kind of code for DT. But for one single value, it was a problem to fix it. Thanks!!!

Comment: I see ;) it tooks me a little bit of time to figure it how to convert your single value in the right format to be use in `DT` ;)

Comment: Now my French friends will be happy :) Thanks!